# Creating a face search engine (like Amazon Rekognition)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, face-recognition, face-detection

I've been thinking for a long time about creating one large database to search people by face photo.

This is a thesis for a **master's degree**. I have my own work in progress, but thought I'd ask here as I'm sure someone has a better idea of how to do it.

### The workflow at the moment:

1. There is a large database with photos of faces (dataset)
2. Finding faces in photos
3. Face centralisation
4. Turning faces into a matrix (128-d feature vector that quantifies the face)

**And here there are questions**...
What is the best algorithm to use for this? Which one would you use?
VGG-Face, Google FaceNet, OpenFace, Facebook DeepFace, DeepID, ArcFace, Dlib....

If you have figured out the algorithm to get a matrix of faces, how would you store this data so that you could search it using the matrix of another face?

How would you store these matrices? Would you train a neural network on them?

Would you use the **nearest neighbour** algorithm?

### Optimisation Problem

With millions of faces, how do you store them all and how do you get a fast search result from them?

**To summarise my question**: What steps would you take to create such a face search engine?

I decided to ask this question because I want to hear a fresh perspective on this issue, as the more I immerse myself, the more confused I get.

I would be happy to hear your solutions to this issue. Or suggestions what databases to use for quick search of matrices or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to my experiments, Facenet and ArcFace are overperforming ones against Vgg-Face, OpenFace and others. When you feed a facial image to these models, they will return a vector. For instance, deepface library has represent function for this task.

You do not have to train a model from scratch, you can use pre-trained ones and deepface comes with all those pre-trained models already.

Once you found the vector representations of your facial database and then you should store these embeddings into a vector database such milvus, weaviate or pinecone.

Instead of using a vector database, you may consider to use an index such as Spotify Voyager, Spotify Annoy or Facebook Faiss. But when data becomes really big, the advantage of a database against index is ability to distribute data into different clusters.

Vector databases are using hnsw algorithm to find nearest neighbours of a given  embedding. You will find the similar faces just in milliseconds even among hundred-billions.

The challenge is to extract embeddings of your facial database in advance and store them into a database / index.

Comment: Very interesting idea! Thanks for the reply, it really helps me to better understand the next steps. I will test the services you recommended!

Answer (score 1):

My advice is:

- use InsightFace for face detection, recognition, making embeddings etc;
- use Elasticsearch to store, index and search / compare face embeddings;
- store face images as files, not as blobs

Comment: While researching this issue I found your comment where you talked about Elasticsearch and just started experimenting in this direction. From my observations ArcFace (from InsightFace), Facenet, Facenet512 are the best in face recognition. 

As I understand it, you have your own face search project. Do you use only Euclidian or Cosine similarity for face search, or have you found a better way?

Comment: I'm using Euclidean distance between two vectors . Elasticsearch has built-in support for the function.